# How do I save associated entities in Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

After a few hours of searching for an answer I have to ask this in StackOverflow.  This seems such a basic thing to do but I'm still quite new to Doctrine2 so forgive me if the answer is simple or if I'm totally looking at Doctrine incorrectly.

My problem is that my foreign keys are not being populated.  I was assuming Doctrine would do it automatically.

For example, I have two entities: `Name` and `EmailAddress` with a OneToMany relationship.  `Name` has many `EmailAddress` and  `EmailAddress` has one `Name`.

Here's pre-populated tables.

```
Table: name       Table: email_address

| id | name |     | id | email_address     | name_id |
|----|------|     |----|-------------------|---------|
| 1  | Luke |     |  1 | luke@starwars.com |       1 |
```

First, I tried just saving into `EmailAddress`:

```php
<?php

$newEmail = new Foo\Entities\Emails();
$newEmail->setEmailAddress('luke.skywalker@starwars.com');

$em->persist($newEmail);
$em->flush();
$em->clear();
```

The `email_address` field is saved, but the foreign key (name_id) is always blank.

I also tried:

```php
<?php

$newEmail = new Foo\Entities\Emails();
$newEmail->setEmailAddress('luke.skywalker@starwars.com');

$newName = $em->getRepository('Foo\Entities\Names')->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);
$newName->addEmail($newEmail);

$em->persist($newName);
$em->flush();
$em->clear();
```

Same result, foreign key is ignored.

Here are my entities:

**Name**

```
/**
 * @namespace
 */
namespace Foo\Entities;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Foo\Entities\Emails;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="names")
 */
class Names
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Emails", mappedBy="names", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="name_id")
     */
    private $emails;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->emails = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setId($value)
    {
        $this->id = $value;
    }
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName($value)
    {
        $this->name = $value;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function addEmail(Emails $email)
    {
        $this->emails->add($email);
    }

    public function getEmails()
    {
        return $this->emails;
    }
}
```

**Emails**

```
/**
 * @namespace
 */
namespace Foo\Entities;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="emails")
 */
class Emails
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $email_address;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $name_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Names", inversedBy="emails")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="name_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $names;

    public function setId($value)
    {
        $this->id = $value;
    }
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setEmailAddress($value)
    {
        $this->email_address = $value;
    }
    public function getEmailAddress()
    {
        return $this->email_address;
    }

    public function setNameId($value)
    {
        $this->name_id = $value;
    }
    public function getNameId()
    {
        return $this->name_id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out.  I should have been setting `Names` to `Emails`.

Modified `Emails` entity:

```
class Emails
{
...
    public function setName(Foo\Entities\Names $name)
    {
        $this->names = $name;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
$name = $em->getRepository('Foo\Entities\Names')->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);

$newEmail = new Foo\Entities\Emails();
$newEmail->setEmailAddress('luke.skywalker@starwars.com');
$newEmail->setName($name);

$em->persist($newEmail);
$em->flush();
$em->clear();
```

Sets the foreign key of new email address record.